# How to define style of a node based on conditional boolean expression in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I want to define "minimum width" of the node based on "ifpgfckedged" parameter. But this not getting set properly, as the check of "ifpgfckedged" fails during \tikzset. I am attaching the code here.

```
%D Latch
\makeatletter
% Define default text labels inside full adder

\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
    latch dff label/.initial=Latch,% 
    latch d label/.initial=,%
    latch q label/.initial=,
    latch ck label/.initial=,
    latch ck edged/.is if=pgfckedged,%


\tikzset{latch/port labels/.style={font=\sffamily\small}}%

\newif\ifpgfckedged

% D Latch shape
\pgfdeclareshape{dlatch}{%

    \savedmacro\operatorparameters{%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\minimumwidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\minimumheight{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\spec{max(\minimumwidth , \minimumheight)/8}%    
    \addtosavedmacro{\spec}%
    }%


  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }%
  % Inherit from rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
  \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  \anchor{D}{
    \pgf@process{\southwest}%
    \operatorparameters%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\spec}
    \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@xa
    \pgf@y=0pt%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@x%
  }


  \anchor{CK}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%    
    \pgf@x=0\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=1\pgf@y%
  }  

  \anchor{Q}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \operatorparameters%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\spec}
    \advance\pgf@x by \pgf@xa
    \pgf@y=0\pgf@y%
    \pgf@x=\pgf@x%
  }


  % Draw the rectangle box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{      
    \operatorparameters%
    % Rectangle box
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}

    \csname pgf@anchor@dlatch@D\endcsname%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\spec}
    \advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}

    \csname pgf@anchor@dlatch@CK\endcsname%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\spec}
    \advance\pgf@yb by \pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}

    % Draw the angle (>) for clock input, if required
    \ifpgfckedged%
        \csname pgf@anchor@dlatch@CK\endcsname%
        \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=0.5\pgf@yb %Check
        \pgf@process{\northeast}%
        \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
        \pgf@process{\southwest}%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@x}{\pgf@yb}}

        \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/minimum width=1.5cm}
    \else%
        \pgfkeys{
    /pgf/minimum width=0.75cm}

    \fi%  

    \csname pgf@anchor@dlatch@Q\endcsname%
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\spec}
    \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}


    % Draw port labels
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }

 \foregroundpath{
   { 
   \operatorparameters%
    % Draw port labels
    \begingroup
    \tikzset{latch/port labels} % Use font from this style
    \tikz@textfont%

    \pgf@anchor@dlatch@center%
      \pgftext[rotate=90,base,at={\pgfpoint{0\pgf@x}{0\pgf@y}}]{%
      \raisebox{-0.5ex}{
      \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/latch dff label}
      }%
      }

    \pgf@anchor@dlatch@D%
      \pgftext[left,base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x+\spec+\radius}{\pgf@y}}]{%
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/latch d label}}%
      }%

    \pgf@anchor@dlatch@CK%
      \pgftext[left,base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x+\spec+\radius}{\pgf@y}}]{%
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/latch ck label}}%
      }%

    \pgf@anchor@dlatch@Q%
      \pgftext[right,base,at={\pgfpoint{\pgf@x-\spec-\radius}{\pgf@y}}]{%
    \raisebox{-.5ex}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/latch q label}}%
      }%

    \endgroup
   }% 
}%

}%

\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

\tikzset{every dlatch node/.style={draw,minimum height=2cm,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,add font=\sffamily}}

\ifpgfckedged%
\tikzset{every dlatch node/.append style={minimum width=1.5cm}}

\else%
\tikzset{every dlatch node/.append style={minimum width=0.75cm}}
\fi%

\makeatother
```

I have shorten the code to highlight my requirement:

```
%D Latch
\makeatletter
% Define default text labels inside full adder

\pgfkeys{/pgf/.cd,
    latch dff label/.initial=Latch,% 
    latch d label/.initial=,%
    latch q label/.initial=,
    latch ck label/.initial=,
    latch ck edged/.is if=pgfckedged,%


\tikzset{latch/port labels/.style={font=\sffamily\small}}%

\newif\ifpgfckedged

% D Latch shape
\pgfdeclareshape{dlatch}{%
%.....
}

\ifpgfckedged%
\tikzset{every dlatch node/.append style={minimum width=1.5cm}}

\else%
\tikzset{every dlatch node/.append style={minimum width=0.75cm}}
\fi%

\makeatother
```

When I try to invoke the node, the minimum width spec is not getting set

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)node[latch ck edged, dlatch,  anchor=CK]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Note: "latch ck edged" is the parameter that invoke "ifpgfckedged".

Comment: Rather than posting code snippets please give a complete minimal working example. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for some one to help you and hence much more likely that some one will.

Comment: You still have not posted a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Having compilable code to start from makes life so much easier, especially in cases like this where we have to work out what your code is trying to do. From the code that you have posted I cannot see where you set `pgfckedged`. I wonder if you are confusing booleans stored in `pgfkeys` and those created using `\newif`, as these are quite different.